# Creating new generic object with wildcard

Tags: java, generics, bounded-wildcard

Please explain this generic code wildcard compile time error:

```
//no compile time error.
List<? extends Number> x = new ArrayList<>(); 

//compile time error.  
List<? extends Number> x = new ArrayList<? extends Number>();
```

Comment: first example works on java 7 obviously and not on java 6 since the optional diamonds werent allowed in 6. second example fails in both

Comment: First one definitely wouldn't work on 6; no diamond operator. As to the rest; you might want to check this resource: http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/JavaGenericsFAQ.html

Answer (score 27, accepted):

It's invalid syntax to instantiate a generic type with wildcards. The type `List<? extends Number>` means a `List` of *some type* that is or extends `Number`. To create an instance of this type doesn't make sense, because with instantiation you're creating something specific:

```
new ArrayList<? extends Number>();//compiler:"Wait, what am I creating exactly?"
```

Generic types with wildcards only make sense for variables and method parameters, because this allows greater freedom in what can be assigned/passed into them.

```
//compiler:"Okay, so passing in a List<Integer> or a List<Double> are both fine"
public void eatSomeNumbers(List<? extends Number> numbers) {
    for (Number number : numbers) {
        System.out.println("om nom " + number + " nom");
    }
}
```

Make sure to keep in mind the limitations that come with using wildcards.

```
List<? extends Number> numList = ...
numList.add(new Integer(3));//compiler:"Nope, cause that might be a List<Double>"
```

As for your first example, the diamond is a new feature in Java 7 that allows the compiler to *infer* the type of the new generic instance, based on the type of the variable it's assigned to. In this case:

```
List<? extends Number> x = new ArrayList<>();
```

The compiler is most likely inferring `new ArrayList<Number>()` here, but what's inferred hardly matters, as long as it's a valid assignment to the given variable. This was the reason for the diamond operator being introduced - that specifying the generic type of a new object was redundant, as long *some* generic type would make it a valid assignment/argument.

This reasoning only makes sense if you remember that generics in Java are a purely compile-time language feature, because of [type erasure](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html), and have no meaning at runtime. Wildcards exist only because of this limitation. By contrast, in C# generic type information sticks around at runtime - and generic wildcards don't exist in that language.

Comment: Is there any way to get around this restriction when instantiating anonymous classes?

Comment: @shmosel I don't think so, but I'm not sure what the benefit would be of e.g. `new Foo<?>() { }` over `new Foo<Object>() { }`. Could you explain more about your use case?

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
 List<? extends Number> x = new ArrayList<Number>();
```

instead.