# Error in Java Generics

Tags: java, generics

I tried the line below:

```
HashMap <Temp,<? extends Action> > p= new HashMap<Temp,  <? extends Action>>()
```

Eclispe is giving me an error

> Multiple markers at this line
>       - Syntax error on token ",", Type expected after 
>        this token
>       - Syntax error on token ",", Type expected after 
>        this token

Any reasons why i am getting this error and how to remove this ?

Comment: Please reformat. It doesn't show up properly.

Comment: Don't use the `<>` around `? extends Action`...and you'll be closer to being right.

Comment: The error is not in Java Generics.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Program to interfaces!

```
Map<Temp, ? extends Action> p = new HashMap<Temp, ? extends Action>();
```

Its better practice.

I noticed that perhaps this wasn't answered correctly. The problem is explained in detail [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/java-generics-what-is-pecs). What will work for you is perhaps

```
Map<Temp, ? super Action> p = new HashMap<Temp, Action>();
```

Hope that helps.

Third edit, I'm new to writing comments so note sure what the process is anyhow here is an example:

```
public void doSomething ()
{
    Map<A, ? super A> p = new HashMap<A, A>();

    A a1 = new A();
    A a2 = new A();

    // AS A CONSUMER
    // Not a problem because at runtime we'll know we can accept A.
    p.put(a1, new B());
    p.put(a2, new C());

    // AS A PRODUCER
    // what do I cast to? No way of knowing if its B or C.
    for (Object a : p.values())
    {
    }

    // Same deal as above is it B or C?
    p.get(a1);
}

class A{}

class B extends A {}

class C extends B {}
```

Comment: You cannot instantiate a type with a wildcard argument.

Comment: Why `? super Action`? Isn't that different from the variable the OP's trying to assign to?

Comment: It basically comes down to what you want to do with the map. If you want to add items (list is a producer) to it then at runtime with <? extends Action> you cannot at runtime know the specific class you are adding therefore you cannot add. If you want to read from the list (list is a consumer) the <? super Action> will guarantee that Action can only be allowed in the list. A much better explanation is available in the link I provided earlier...

Comment: I think we're on the same page about PECS. But really, why does the OP use a wildcard at all? The question's too opaque to answer anything beyond the syntax errors. Anyway +1 for correcting and adding to your answer. It's unfortunate you got stuck with downvotes.

Comment: Yeah agreed probably need more to the context to really understand if a wildcard is even necessary here.

Answer (score 4):

Have this:

```
HashMap <Temp, ? extends Action > p= new HashMap<Temp,  *>();
```

You need two types for a map. Type for key, and a type for value. You cannot surround the second (value) type with `<` & `>` because it is just not allowed.

I also recommend programming to an interface, note the declared type is an interface:

```
Map<Temp, ? extends Action > p = new HashMap<Temp, ? extends Action>();
```

EDIT

As pointed out, you cannot instantiate a variable with a wildcard generic type. Please change * to the type that you need.

Comment: You cannot instantiate a type with a wildcard argument.

Answer (score 2):

This will compile :

```
Map<Temp, ? extends Action> p = new HashMap<Temp, Action>();
```

Or with Java 7:

```
Map<Temp, ? extends Action> p = new HashMap<>();
```

You had extra `<` and `>` in the value type parameter, causing a syntax error. Past that, [you can't instantiate a generic type using a wildcard as a type parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9147768/697449).

You'll also notice I changed the variable to `Map` instead of `HashMap` - it's good practice to [program to interfaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383947/what-does-it-mean-to-program-to-an-interface) instead of implementations, like [winged's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11943077/697449) mentions.