# Generics wildcard instantiation

Tags: java, generics, wildcard, declaration, instantiation

I was reviewing someone else's code the other day and I came across a line that raised some concern. To simplify, say I have a generic Class A and an abstract Class B. Is the following instantiation allowed and if so, why?

```
Object obj = new A<? extends B>();
```

I personally have never seen an instantiation like the above, although a declaration such as

```
A<? extends B> obj = null;
```

would certainly hold. I've always used the wildcard in generics to declare method parameters, so I may just not have the experience.

Comment: what version of java you use?

Comment: related if not duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9147129/creating-new-generic-object-with-wildcard and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12200136/cannot-instantiate-type-in-generics?lq=1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually `new A<? extends B>()` does not compile. It has been consistently illegal since Java 5.

But I guess your original example was something like `new A<X<? extends B>>()`. The latter is legal in recent versions of Java.

The idea is, when instantiating an object, the value for type parameters can be any non-wildcard type. `? extends B` is a wildcard type, so it is disallowed. But `X<? extends B>` is not a wildcard type, though it *has* a wildcard type as a component. So you can say legally call `new A<X<? extends B>>()`.

The rules makes sense if you think about it this way. Ultimately it is a byproduct of the more fundamental rule that a wildcard type like `? extends B` cannot be the *declared* type of a field or variable. If `A` is defined as

```
class A<T> {
    T value;
}
```

then the hypothetical `new A<? extends B>().value` would be a field *declared of type* `? extends B`. Since that is illegal, so is the instantiation. But `new A<X<? extends B>>()` does not have that problem.

Comment: Pretty good answer but I don't think the reasoning in the second half makes much sense. If a variable `a` is typed as `A<? extends B>` that doesn't mean `a.value` is *declared* as `? extends B` - `value` is declared as `T` where `A` declares `T`. `a.value` does *evaluate* to `? extends B`. See my answer to a similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9147768/697449).

Comment: @PaulBellora Admitted, I was not very clear in the second part. What I intended to say was that there is a difference between the putative type of the _expression_ `a.value` and the declared type of the the _variable_ `a.value`. Note that a variable is both an r-value and an l-value, so if you where allowed to create a variable/field with a wildcard type `? extends T` (or `? super T`) it would be an inherently handicapped variable. You would not be able to use it as an r-value, (l-value respectively). Now, that is tolerable for an ordinary reference `a`, but never for `this`.