# Why can't wildcards be used at the top level during instantiation, but they can be used at every other level during instantiation?

Tags: java, generics, types, wildcard, instantiation

For example, if I have the following class:

```
class MyObject<T> {}
```

Why is this possible:

```
class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {        
        MyObject<MyObject<?>> moMo = new MyObject<MyObject<?>>();
    }
}
```

but not this:

```
class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyObject<?> mo = new MyObject<?>();
    }
}
```

I don't understand why one of these would be possible and not the other. I'm starting to believe that these many little discrepancies weren't intentionally designed, but are instead just quirks in the language.

---

I understand there have been similar questions asked on here ([this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18622554/are-we-allowed-to-use-wildcard-during-instantiation), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26146371/how-to-instantiate-generics-using-wild-card), and [this](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/194107/why-it-is-not-possible-to-instantiating-types-with-wildcards-in-java)); however, none have answered *why* one is allowed and not the other.

Answer (score 0):

Consider

```
    List<?> list1 = new ArrayList<>();
    List<?> list2 = new ArrayList<List<?>>();
    List<?> list3 = new ArrayList<?>(); // WRONG

    list2.add(new ArrayList<Integer>()); // WRONG
```

In the third wrong case an actual List is *created* with a generic parameter class **not bound** to the declared parameter class on the left (also `?`).
**A wild card type may not be instantiated directly.**

You might do `new ArrayList<Integer>()` (or `new ArrayList()`) telling what type is allowed. These are stored in `Class.getType parameters()`. Hence `new ArrayList<?>()` cannot be stored in the objects actual class for that ArrayList instance. Runtime class erasure does not hold 100% for generic classes.

In the second case this immediate instantiation does not happen.

That such usage of wild card types are cumbersome/impractical is shown by the `add`,
where the actual `list2` might be a `List<List<String>>` instead.

For those that have experience stronger type systems in other languages: better
refrain from trying to use too clever type expressions.

Comment: There are a lot of good points in this answer, but ultimately it doesn't answer my question. You mention that **a wildcard type may not be instantiated directly**, but my question is *why*? I'm especially curious because it's perfectly fine to instantiate it indirectly.

Comment: I have added to the answer (_"You might do...."_). I hope the explanation is indeed correct.

Comment: I don't believe those types are available through `Class#getTypeParameters`. `Class#getTypeParameters` just returns the name of the generic parameter name. So for `Map` it returns `K` and `V`, rather than `String` and `String`