# Allocating generic type with bounded wildcard using diamond

Tags: java, generics, wildcard, bounded-wildcard

The following code:

`Set<? extends Integer> set = new HashSet<>();`

Compiles fine. However, the essence of using the diamond notation is just for not rewriting the LHS type parameter again. This means that the statement above should be equivalent with the following:

`Set<? extends Integer> set = new HashSet<? extends Integer>();`

But as it turns out, it's not. I guess it's rational since the compiler doesn't know the object's type parameter since it's the wildcard ('?'). When not using bounded type parameters, everything works fine so I supposed the same would apply for any case. But why allow the syntax anyway? What is, in the end, the type parameter of the first statement?

Thanks

Comment: See if these Q&As help with understanding generics: [What is PECS (Producer Extends Consumer Super)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/what-is-pecs-producer-extends-consumer-super), [Difference between <? super T> and <? extends T> in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4343202/difference-between-super-t-and-extends-t-in-java), and [Creating new generic object with wildcard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9147129/creating-new-generic-object-with-wildcard).

Comment: This question may even be a duplicate of the last one I listed.

Comment: See also: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/194107/why-it-is-not-possible-to-instantiating-types-with-wildcards-in-java

Comment: Set<? extends Integer> set = new HashSet<? extends Integer>();
The above statement is not allowed, as the HashSet Object need to be of a concrete type, not a wildcard or generic.

Below would be valid expressions:
Set<? extends Integer> set = new HashSet<Integer>();
Set<? extends Number> set = new HashSet<Number>();
Set<? extends Number> set = new HashSet<Integer>();
Set<? extends Number> set = new HashSet<Double>();

Comment: Also, Set<? extends Integer> set = new HashSet<>(); is a valid expression as compiler will infer the HashSet type. But with new HashSet<? extends Integer>(); the compiler is stuck with the wild card and not an actual Object type and there is no scope for the compiler to infer.